# How do I remove all the <br> tags from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a big string like

```
Hello<br>I am a On then sake home is am leaf<br> Of suspicion do departure at extremely he 
believing.<br> Do know said mind do rent they oh hope of <br> General enquire picture letters garrets on
offices of no on<br> Say one hearing between excited evening all inhabit thought you<br> Style begin mr
heard by in music tried do<br> To unreserved projection no introduced invitation<br> .... 1200 words.
```

Now I want to replace those `<br>` tags with " ". I don't know regex, can someone please help me ?
And I used javascript string replace and it didn't work.

Comment: Please add to your question your attempt with `replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `<br>` for regular space `" "`.

```js
const yourString = "Hello<br>I am a On then sake home is am leaf<br> Of suspicion do departure at extremely he believing.<br> Do know said mind do rent they oh hope of <br> General enquire picture letters garrets on offices of no on<br> Say one hearing between excited evening all inhabit thought you<br> Style begin mr heard by in music tried do<br> To unreserved projection no introduced invitation<br>"

const result = yourString
.replace(/<br>/gi," ")      // REPLACES ALL <br> OCCURRENCES FOR A REGULAR SPACE
.replace(/\s+/g," ")        // REPLACES POSSIBLE MULTIPLE SPACES FOR A SINGLE SPACE
.trim();                    // REMOVES POSSIBLE SPACES FROM THE BEGINNING AND END OF THE STRING
  
console.log(result);
```

Replacing `<br>` for regular new lines `"\n"`.

```js
const yourString = "Hello<br>I am a On then sake home is am leaf<br> Of suspicion do departure at extremely he believing.<br> Do know said mind do rent they oh hope of <br> General enquire picture letters garrets on offices of no on<br> Say one hearing between excited evening all inhabit thought you<br> Style begin mr heard by in music tried do<br> To unreserved projection no introduced invitation<br>"

const result = yourString
.replace(/<br>\s*/gi,"\n")      // REPLACES ALL <br> FOLLOWED BY 0 OR MORE SAPCES FOR A NEW LINE
.trim();                    // REMOVES POSSIBLE SPACES FROM THE BEGINNING AND END OF THE STRING
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow, it worked. Thank you so much brother. Can you please tell me how to add a new line where the <br> tags were ? I mean instead of " ", I want to make a new line

Comment: I've added it to the answer. See if that helps.